# changing a letter to another letter from another language - python

Tags: python

Hi Sorry if you didn't understand what I want to achieve in the Question title but what I want to do is split a word into letters then changing the letter from English to Arabic for example

```
text = "Hello"

word_list = []

for i in range(0, len(text)):
    word_list.append(text[i])
    i += 1

print(word_list)
```

This code will split the word into ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']

After that the letters `H,e,l,l,o` will be the letters i would it to be in the values
Here is what I have tried

```
ا = '6'
أ = '6'
ب = '12'
ت = '24'
ث = '9'
ج = 'z'
ح = 'y'
خ = '12T'
د = '18'
ذ = '6y'
ر = '9z'
ز = '2418'
س = '7'
ش = 'oz'
ص = '5s'
ض = 'x3'
ط = 'vi'
ظ = '88'
ع = '3xy'
غ = 'z'
ف = '93'
ق = 'o0'
ك = 'so9'
ل = '5s9'
م = 'k9'
ن = 'b6'
ه = '39o'
و = '9z2'
ي = '612'

text = "Hello"

word_list = []

for i in range(0, len(text)):
    word_list.append(text[i])
    i += 1

print(word_list)

string = word_list

# Prints the string by replacing all
print(string.replace(word_list, A))
```

in another word i want to make a program that translate a word to a word in other Lang But notice I really must have the values like A = ا or B = ب

Comment: Note that you don't have to loop through the characters in a string to split it. Instead, you can just do `string = "Some string"` then call `string.split()`. Also, the `i += 1` statement has no effect on the loop, since, on the next iteration of the `for` loop, the iterator will move to the next element in the iterable `range(0, len(text))`.

Comment: simpler `word_list = list(text)`

Comment: You should create dictionary `data = { "A": "|", "B": "ب", ...}` and later use loop `for char in text: result.append( data[char] )`

Comment: Holy justification Batman, how do you keep track of all the right-to-left-to-right-to-left assigns there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep it as dictionary

```
translation = { "A": "|", "B": "ب", ...}
```

and then you can conver it using loop

```
text = "Hello"

result = []

for char in text:
    result.append( translation[char] )

result = "".join(result)

print(result)
```

If there are chars which may not be traslated then you chould check it and keep original char

```
for char in text:
    if char in translation:
        result.append( translation[char] )
    else:
        result.append( char )
```

---

**BTW:**

There are also standard functions [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)

```
translation = { "A": "|", "B": "ب"}

table = str.maketrans(translation)

result = "Hello ABBA".translate(table)

print(result)
```

Result

```
'Hello |بب|'
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\proj\proj11\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    result.append(translation[char])
KeyError: 'H'

Comment: If you use first version then you have to create full dictionary with all chars. And in second version I use `if/else` to keep chars which are not in dictionary.

Comment: if I used the third version the last one after btw. its not showing any result or any errors

Comment: did you use `print()` to display it ? I add `print()` to answer.